# How to add a method with ES6 Rest to a JS object

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, spread-syntax

I have a Person constructor and I want to add a method supposed to add friends. I want to allow my user to pass a variable number of friends so I thought about the new "rest" feature of ES6. Sadly, I can't find my way out. Here's my first try (error : "Uncaught TypeError: f.addFriends is not a function(…)"):

```
// Persons creator
function Person(name){
    this.name = name;
    this.friends = [];
    this.addFriends = function(...a){
      a.forEach(function(d){this.friends.push(d)});
    }
}

// Create three persons
f = new Person("Fanny");
e = new Person("Eric");
j = new Person("John");

// add Eric & Fanny as friends of Fanny
f.addFriends(e,j);
```

I've also tried the following code (no error, but no friends added):

```
// Persons creator
function Person(name){
    this.name = name;
    this.friends = [];
}

Person.prototype.addFriends = function(...a){
   a.forEach(function(d){this.friends.push(d)});
}


// Create three persons
f = new Person("Fanny");
e = new Person("Eric");
j = new Person("John");

// add Eric & Fanny as friends of Fanny
f.addFriends(e,j);
```

What am I doing wrong?
Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Both your snippets work for me (i.e. do not throw the error you're describing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you use a callback inside the `forEach`, the `this` doesn't refer to the object. Bind the callback to `this`:

```
Person.prototype.addFriends = function(...a){
   a.forEach(function(d){this.friends.push(d)}.bind(this));
}
```

Since we're using ES6, you can use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) instead. Arrow functions lexically bind the `this` value:

```
Person.prototype.addFriends = function(...a){
   a.forEach((d) => this.friends.push(d));
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your perfect answer Ori!

Comment: You're welcome, although I must say that nils and Denys answers are more elegant.

Comment: _"Arrow functions bind automatically to the current context"_ Arrow functions have their own context. `this` is taken from the enclosing environment, that's all.

Comment: The idea was "Arrow functions bind this automatically to the current context", but I find that my current edit reflects it better.

Answer (score 3):

`forEach` takes a callback, which is usually called in the global context (`window` in the browser). You would need to either pass the current `this` into `forEach` as the second argument.

Or could avoid the whole `this` problem altogether and just [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) the Arrays:

```
function Person(name){
    this.name = name;
    this.friends = [];
    this.addFriends = function(...a){
      this.friends = this.friends.concat(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a much better solution than using concat, look at my answer. BTW your code has the side effect of replacing the origina array instead of augmenting it.

Comment: Unfortunately, your solution creates nested arrays instead of a single array. And yes, this does replace the current array with a new array. Most of the time, this shouldn't be a problem though. See Bergi's comment to fix your code.

Answer (score 1):

`this`, in the callback passed to [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), isn't your instance of Person in this code:

```
Person.prototype.addFriends = function(...a){
   a.forEach(function(d){this.friends.push(d)});
}
```

You could use the new arrow function to have the right context:

```
Person.prototype.addFriends = function(...a){
   a.forEach((d) => {this.friends.push(d)});
}
```

but there's a more elegant solution here:

```
Person.prototype.addFriends = function(...a){
   this.friends.push(...a);
}
```

Comment: You probably meant `.push(...a)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a new feature from ECMAScript 6 -> **classes**

1. define your class:

   class Person {

   ```
   constructor(name) {
       this.name = name;
       this.friends = [];
   }

   addFriends(friends) {
       // do someting with friends
       this.friends = friends
   }
   ```

   }

then you are able to create new instance of the Person

```
var p = new Person("Jack");
```

and add some new friends

```
p.addFriends(....)
```